# How to find exact command line for Build command using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, unreal-engine4

Our team has been automating the build process for a UE4 game. We are able to successfully compile all targets using Visual Studio 2019 (with the Build function), but we are having trouble finding the correct syntax for the build console command for a specific target.

We tried getting the command from the build output log, but we only found something like this:

1>------ Build started: Project: [ProjectName], Configuration: Development_Editor x64 ------

We want to know how to get the exact command that Visual Studio runs when compiling a specific target with the Build button.

Thank you